# How to read data from postgresql in python using Flask and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I started creating a flask application as I will be needing to do some visualization of some data that was recently transferred to a local postgresql database.

I have a lot of tables (33) which all have the same kind of content as currently just works as containers for different types of data (They contain a JSON object that's different in each of the tables though).

The tables are named "Table_#" (where # symbolizes a number among a defined subset of numbers).

## models.py

I have created the following model:

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, JSON, Text
from app import db

class Table_1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'

    id = db.Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    did = db.Column(Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)
    data = db.Column(JSON)
    db_timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<1_Data %r>' % (self.did)
```

to test if I can actually grab some data from my postgresql.

## __init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views, models
```

## config.py

In my config.py I have the following:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/backupdata" //Ofc <username> and <password> isn't my credentials..
```

In my terminal (Windows cmd) I've tried running the following:

```
>python
>>>from app import db, models
>>>row = models.Table_1.query.get(1)
```

But for some reason when I try to print my row nothing is output.

I was hoping someone could have an idea why that is?

Comment: Do you have a record in the table with a primary key of 1?

Comment: Does the above command get the id's of the rows? I thought it was like just get 1 row.. But if it's the ID of the row then that is my problem. How would I got about getting a "random" row or a random subset of rows?

Comment: [`get` does a primary key lookup](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get).

Comment: Then I am definitively using the wrong command. Thanks for informing me. I will get right on checking the documentation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my model a bit, to see that I actually got a specific row.

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, JSON, Text
from app import db

class Table_1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'

    id = db.Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    did = db.Column(Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)
    data = db.Column(JSON)
    db_timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<1_Data %r, %r>' % (self.did, self.id)
```

And then the following query made me aware that actually have a working connection to SQLAlchemy through my flask application.

```
row = models.Table_910.query.filter_by(did='357139052424715').first()
```

Knowing that I have one item with the above did I could get a single item:

```
<1_Data '357139052424715', 738390911>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your answer, you would need to use the `firts()` method. Another option would be to limit your query as follows:

`Table.query.limit(1).all()`

This way you don't need a filter and can just retrieve the first item in the query (which seems to be what you wanted to do originally with `query.get(1)`

See [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/queries/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This sloution is with postgres and Flask without SQLAlchemy

```
@app.route('/contextget', methods=['GET']) 
def contextget():
    sql_query ="""SELECT * FROM context"""
    out = cur.execute(sql_query)
    context_records = cur.fetchall() 
    ContextRootKeys = []
    outp ="Print each row and it's columns values"
    for row in context_records:
        ContextRootKeys.append(row[1])
    conn.commit()
    print(ContextRootKeys)
    return outp
```